# value from a method to bind in Viewbag methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Trying to return value from GetStage_details() methods and bind it to ViewBag.Stage_details but getting `error at var result`.

Error msg is :

> can't implicitly convert type `oracle.ManagedDtaAccessclient.oracledatareader` to `System.Collection.generic.List<Models.Stage_Details`."

Any idea how to resolve it show that correct value return from table and bind to     `ViewBag.Stage_details`  will be appreciated.

```
public class Stage_details
{
    public int Stage_Cd { get; set; }
    public string Stage_Desc { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index_shift()
{
    ViewBag.Stage_details = new SelectList(GetStage_details(), "Stage_Cd", "Stage_Desc");
}

private List<Stage_details> GetStage_details()
{
    List<Stage_details> Stage_detail = new List<Stage_details>();
    OracleConnection conn = new 
    OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Mycon"].ToString());           
        conn.Open();
    string cmdText= "select a.stage_cd,a.stage_desc from Stage_Mst a";
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(cmdText,conn);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    var result = command.ExecuteReader();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Seems like ExecuteReader returns an oracle data reader class rather than List<Stage_Details>. Also, are you missing a "return" in your GetStage_details() method?

Comment: @ekke yes return was missing i updated it  and yes ExecuteReader returns an oracle data reader class rather than List<Stage_Details> ,but how to return it in list like format

Comment: You can use OracleDataAdapter Class: DataSet dataSet = new DataSet(); using (OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter())
{
  dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
  dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
}

Comment: @SebastianSiemens but how to return value in GetStage_details() method in list form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.8), You could read each element from reader and build `Stage_detail` object inside loop, like the following code :

```
private List<Stage_details> GetStage_details()
{
    List<Stage_details> Stage_detail = new List<Stage_details>();

    OracleConnection conn = new
    OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Mycon"].ToString());
    conn.Open();

    string cmdText = "select a.stage_cd,a.stage_desc from Stage_Mst a";
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(cmdText, conn)
    {
        CommandType = CommandType.Text
    };

    using (OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Stage_detail.Add(new Stage_details { Stage_Cd = (int)reader["stage_cd"], Stage_Desc = reader["stage_desc"].ToString() });
        }
    }

    return Stage_detail;
}
```

I hope you find this helpful.